# Databricks DLT Syntax for Read_Stream Union

Tags: python, databricks, delta-live-tables

New to DLT, struggling with the python syntax for returning a dataframe via the dlt.read_stream operator as a union (unionByName) of two other live tables.

My pipeline is as follows..

WORKS: Table1:

```
@dlt.table()
def table_1()
   return spark.sql (''' select mergeKey, date_seq, colN, case/when.., cast.. from live.raw_table_1 ''')
```

WORKS: Table2:

```
@dlt.table()
def table_2()
   return spark.sql (''' select mergeKey, date_seq, colN, case/when.., cast.. from live.raw_table_2 ''')
```

PROBLEM: View_Union:

```
    @dlt.view()
    def pre_merge_union_v
    --> question: what's the syntax to [return dlt.read_stream("df_unioned").as.table1.unionByName(table2)
```

Create Silver Table:

```
dlt.create_streaming_live_table("silver_table")
```

Finally, Apply Changes Into Silver:

```
dlt.apply_changes(
   target = "silver_table"),
   source = "pre_merge_union_v"
   keys = ["mergeKey"],
   sequence_by = "date_seq"
```

---

TRIED:

I tried to create my View_Union view as:

```
@dlt.view()
def pre_merge_union_v:
   df_table1 = spark.table("live.raw_table1")
   df_table2 = spark.table("live.raw_table2")
   df_unioned = df_table1.unionByName(df_table2)
     return df_unioned
```

However, when the pipeline runs, it complains that pre_merge_union_v must be a READ_STREAM VIEW (as it's merging into a streaming live table, I assume)

Using `return dlt.read_stream(df_unioned)` also generates an error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've answered my own question. Hope it helps.

```
return dlt.read_stream("raw_table1").unionByName(dlt.read_stream("raw_table2"))
```